# A simple hangman game on tkinter gui gets stuck

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import*
import random
wlist ="monday friday sunday blue orange red brown ".split()
sword = random.choice(wlist)    
def lets_begin():       
    guess = ent.get()
    lb2["text"]= ent.get()
    ent.delete(0,5)
    guesses=""    
    turns = 5
    while turns > 0:
        failed = 0
        for char in sword:
            if char in guesses:
                lb1["text"] = char
            else:
                lb1["text"] = "-"
                failed += 1
        if failed==0:
            lb1["text"]="you won"
            break           
        guesses += guess
        if guess not in sword:
            turns -= 1
            lb2["text"]="you are wrong"
        if turns == 0:
            lb2["text"]="game is over.The answer was {0}".format(sword)    
wn=Tk()
wn.geometry("400x300+10+10")
wn.config(bg="silver")    
but1=Button(wn,text="playx",command=lets_begin)
but1.place(x=20,y=95)
ent=Entry(wn,width=12)
ent.place(x=10,y=70)
lb1=Label(bg="pink",width=10)
lb1.place(x=10,y=10)

lb2=Label(bg="yellow",width=28)
lb2.place(x=110,y=5)
lb2["text"]="Days of the week\n and some colors...."+sword
wn.mainloop()
```

I am trying to code a simple "hangman" game in Python using Tkinter GUI. it works on console IDE. I just wanted to modify and test it on TKINTER GUI, But I failed to make it run...I will be happy if you help me.
lb1["text"] doesn't print as many "-" as "the secret word" is supposed to have.
and it stucks every time I enter the correct character8((

Comment: tkinter has special look - `mainloop()`  - which works all time to get key/mouse events from system and send to widgets in window, update widgets, redraw widget and window. If you run some long-running function - like your `while` loop - then mainloop can't update GUI and it looks like it freeze. It is better to use `if` instead of `while` to check chars only once when you press button. You will have to keed `turns outside function to keep it between two executions of function which checks chars.

Comment: to get more `-` you have to use `+=` in  `lb1["text"] += "-"` and `lb1["text"] += char`

Comment: I think you would need two buttons - one to start game and choose new word, second to check chars after you put new char in entry. Or you would have to bind() event to entry which run function (which check chars) everytime you change text in entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made version which use button only to check it once - without `while` loop which stops `mainloop()` and tkinter can't work correctly. After you put char in entry you have to press button, it checks this char (and other variables) and it ends work so `mainloop()` can run it again and it can wait when you press button next time.

I use `global` to keep values outside function so they will be not deleted between two executions.

I don't set `sword` and other values at start but in `reset()` so I can run it many times to set new `sword` before next game.

I add some spaces and empty lines to make code more readable.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

wlist = "monday friday sunday blue orange red brown ".split()

def reset():
    '''reset values before first and next game'''
    global turns
    global guesses
    global sword

    turns = 5
    guesses = ""
    sword = random.choice(wlist)    

def check():
    ''' check only once when button is pressed'''
    global turns
    global guesses
    global sword

    # get value from entry
    guess = ent.get()
    guesses += guess

    # check new char in sword to display '-'
    failed = 0
    lb1["text"] = ''

    for char in sword:
        if char in guesses:
            lb1["text"] += char
        else:
            lb1["text"] += "-"
            failed += 1

    # check result
    if failed == 0:
        lb1["text"] = "you won"
        # end of game - set variables before next game
        reset()
        # display after reset because it needs value in `sword`
        lb2["text"] = "Days of the week\n and some colors.... " + sword
    else:
        if guess not in sword:
            turns -= 1
            lb2["text"] = "you are wrong"
        else:
            lb2["text"] = "good choice"

        if turns == 0:
            lb2["text"] = "Game is over.\nThe answer was {0}".format(sword)    
            # end of game - set variables before next game
            reset()
            # display after reset because it needs value in `sword`
            lb2["text"] = "Days of the week\n and some colors.... " + sword

    # clear entry before next char 
    ent.delete(0,'end')

# --- main ---

wn = tk.Tk()
wn.geometry("400x300+10+10")
wn.config(bg="silver")

but1 = tk.Button(wn, text="Check char", command=check)
but1.place(x=20, y=95)

ent = tk.Entry(wn, width=12)
ent.place(x=10, y=70)

lb1 = tk.Label(bg="pink", width=10)
lb1.place(x=10, y=10)

lb2 = tk.Label(bg="yellow", width=28)
lb2.place(x=110, y=5)

# set variables before first game
reset()
# display after reset because it needs value in `sword`
lb2["text"] = "Days of the week\n and some colors.... " + sword


wn.mainloop()
```

Comment: That's exactly what I am after. You did a good job. Thank you furas.